# Get relationship with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using `laravel 6.16.0` and I have two migrations:

*person*

```
  Schema::create('persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('full_name')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->date('date_of_birth')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('phone')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('office')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->timestamps();
  });
```

*senator_attributes*

```
        Schema::create('senator_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('persons_id')->default('999999')->nullable($value = true);
            $table->string('party')->nullable($value = true);
            // ...
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

My models look like the following:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

}
```

```
class SenatorAttributes extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'senator_attributes';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'persons_id');
    }
}
```

I was wondering, how can I query all Persons and get for each person their attributes?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You haven't actually defined the relationship between the `Person` model and the `SenatorAttributes` model so until you do that you can't easily do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pretty straight forward solutions you can directly do:

First, you need to add the `SenatorAttributes` model inside the `Person` model. You can do so like the following:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'persons';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function senator_attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SenatorAttributes::class, 'persons_id'); // or you can use hasOne if person model is supposed to only have one single senator attribute.
    }
}
```

Now to load senator attributes for each person.

`Solution 1`, with Eager(early/desperate) Loading:

```
$persons = Person::with('senator_attributes')->get();
```

`Solution 2`, on-demand loading:

```
$persons = Person::all();
foreach($persons as $person) {
    $senator_attribures = $person->senator_attributes;
    // write your logic here...
}
```

Solution 1 is fine as long as you don't load all of the rows at the runtime. If you are planning to load hundreds/thousands of models, consider [chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) the solution and use eager loading with it.

Learn more about Laravel Eloquent Relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships).

Now, read the following if you are interested in best practices.

I don't want to sound nosey, but I personally follow the following ground rules while working on any project.

- Table name should always be in plural and model name to be in singular form. For example, `persons` table will have `Person` model.
- Foreign keys should always be in `singular form of referenced table` + `referenced column of the referenced table`. For example, if you wish to add a `person` reference to `senator_attributes` table, you should add `person_id` column to `senator_attributes` table.

Fact, Laravel supports this naming convention, above all, you save yourself time and maintain the consistency and practice across the teams and projects.